# TestComplete : Wait to a dropdown is displayed on screen before doing an action

Tags: testing, end-to-end, testcomplete, web-testing

I am using the recorder of the testComplete Software

I would like to adjust the result for doing for making an end to end website test.

But before that I have an issue when I try to replay the record result: I have a dropdown list that takes few seconds before be displayed.
On picture it is the Droipdown list where the item 'Admin' has to be selected

[image: Admin takes few seconds before be displayed]

[image]

I saw ther is a Delay method in tools, and it woeks is i put this action but I don't see a WaitFor method like I saw in Testcafé or Ranorex

Please Do you know how to do it and could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found : you have to copy paste the action with the element you want to wait.

Move the new action before the click action and choose visibleOnScreen

[image]

[image]